# How to catch specific database error on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to ask about engine in SQLAlchemy.

Here's my code:

```
try:
    engine = create_engine('postgres://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/db')
    engine.connect()
except DatabaseError:
    print('Database Error : ', sys.exc_info()[1])
```

How can I catch an exception for a specific error like "database does not exist" or "wrong password/user name", etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Python DBAPI doesn't have specific exceptions for these things, so the best you can do is to parse the string:

```
try:
    # code
except DatabaseError, e:
    if "database does not exist" in str(e):
         # do something
```